# searchController abnormal behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

```
class SearchMembers: UITableViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("MEMBERS", comment: "")

            let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            self.definesPresentationContext = true
            search.searchResultsUpdater = self
            search.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            navigationItem.searchController = search
            navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

    }
```

When I perform segue from a tableview cell, I can see the search controller as It should be but When I perform a segue from a navigation bar item, I only see a space without search bar. Then, I go back to the previous view, search controller bar appears there.

It goes back to normal behavior If I go back to search view again.

A possible bug?

[image]

Should be:
[image]

EDIT:

I realized that If I unselect "Animates" option from segue settings, I don't get an empty space in searchController view but I still get an empty space when I go back to main view

Comment: Are you using two different types of segue i.e. show & push

Comment: @Scriptable All show segue

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz, is there any chance you are using UIAppearance class to alter elements appearance?

Comment: @T.Pasichnyk nope. I found out that if I navigate to another tab and then come back to the main view this problem goes away. So the problem happens when first app loads with this main view. Very interesting

Comment: can you show us an image of the debug view hierarchy when the problem occurred ?

Answer (score 0):

Check how your segue is set up. Do you have one segue which is connected from view controller to viewcontroller or is it connected from the tableview to the other view controller or maybe you have two segues?? as in this situation you should be using one segue just triggering it in different places

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueIdentifier")
```

Have a look at this code i have quickly made up for you:
You can also try it from my github and compare it with yours. The searchbar appears as it should be in both cases. 
https://github.com/verebes1/SearchBarHelp

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UITableViewController {

    var items = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    //MARK: - Tableview methods
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMembers", sender: self)
    }


    //MARK: - Segue setup
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        /* Put any preparation here if needed */
    }

    //MARK: Navbar Button action
    @IBAction func searchBarButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMembers", sender: self)
    }

}
```

and the second viewController:

```
import UIKit

class SearchMembersController: UITableViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    var members = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("MEMBERS", comment: "")

        let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        //search.searchResultsUpdater = self
        search.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        navigationItem.searchController = search
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return members.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = members[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

[image: Segue]

[image: Segue setup]

referring to your code from the comment:

```
leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Profile.searchMembers), for: .touchUpInside) self.settingsButton.customView = leftButton
```

this should call 
`performSegue(withIdentifier: "profileToMembers", sender: self)` 
instead Profile.searchMembers. Probably that is going wrong you can wrap that perform in an @objc function like

```
@objc func segueToMembers(){ 
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "profileToMembers", sender: self) 
}
```

and then call it

```
leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segueToMembers), for: .touchUpInside) self.settingsButton.customView = leftButton
```

Comment: Segue is from view controller to view controller and I perform segue from navigationbar item (addTarget)

Comment: leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Profile.searchMembers), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.settingsButton.customView = leftButton

Comment: self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "profileToMembers", sender: self)

Comment: Try only using one segue and then performSegue as I showed tou

Comment: I would need to try your code can you upload to github. As If I try to do a similar thing it works. I only call the same segue with performSegue

Comment: I have edited my answer it should help now. Give it a go

Comment: Thank you. I checked everything step by step but I am still having the problem.

Comment: Download my project from github maybe the full setup will help you more.

Comment: Already downloaded and opened. My problem must be caused by something else because I did everything just like your way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173972/discussion-between-utku-dalmaz-and-ad-progress).

Comment: Any luck with the searchbar??